# How do I programmatically create a new instance from hosted containerized web app which running on azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, devops, azure-web-app-service

I have published and hosted asp .net core web app using azure pipelines. Web app running inside docker container. I want programmatically provision another web app using docker image which was available in azure container registry. The web app should run on a separate url. This url can be configurable. A user will be able to give a name for the web app and can create a web app. I hope to create a separate app for doing this task. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: So essentially you are trying to create a service where users can create and configure the URL of their own apps, while you supply the docker image?

Comment: Yes. That was the requirement. Is it possible to create separate SQL database for a newly created app in the same SQL server which is running on Azure. The requirement is to users will be able to create their own application when they provide their company details. We are using asp .net core 2.2 with dockers.